# Extracting a table from webpage with regex

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, html-table

I want to extract the table containing the [IP blocks from this site](http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/za.html).

Looking at the HTML source I can clearly see that the area I want is structured like this:

```
[CONTENT BEFORE TABLE]
<table border="1" cellpadding="6" bordercolor="#000000">
[IP ADDRESSES AND OTHER INFO]
</table>
[CONTENT AFTER TABLE]
```

So I wrote this little snippet:

```
import urllib2,re
from lxml import html
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/za.html')

content = response.read()

print re.match(r"(.*)<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"6\" bordercolor=\"#000000\">(.*)</table>(.*)",content)
```

The content's of the page is fetched (and correct) without problems. The regex match always returns `None` however (the print here is just for debugging).

Considering the structure of the page, I can't understand why there isn't a match. I would expect there to be three groups with the second group being the table contents.

Comment: Please use an HTML parser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @sshashank124 Not an option in this case.

Comment: Does your task specifically require you to use regex?

Comment: @sshashank124 Yes, I need to demonstrate regex to extract the table and I can't figure out why it doesn't work with this large string when I can get regex to work on other strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `.` does not match newlines.  You need to specify the [dot-all flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) to have it do this:

```
re.match(..., content, re.DOTALL)
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> import re
>>> content = '''
... [CONTENT BEFORE TABLE]
... <table border="1" cellpadding="6" bordercolor="#000000">
... [IP ADDRESSES AND OTHER INFO]
... </table>
... [CONTENT AFTER TABLE]
... '''
>>> pat = r"(.*)<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"6\" bordercolor=\"#000000\">(.*)</table>(.*)"
>>> re.match(pat, content, re.DOTALL)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02520520>
>>> re.match(pat, content, re.DOTALL).group(2)
'\n[IP ADDRESSES AND OTHER INFO]\n'
>>>
```

The dot-all flag can also be activated by using `re.S` or by placing `(?s)` at the start of your pattern.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the DOTALL

Answer (score 1):

For parsing `HTML` i would prefer `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/za.html').read())
for x in soup.find_all('table', attrs={'border':"1",'cellpadding':"6",'bordercolor':"#000000"}):
    print x
```

for better result:

```
for x in soup.find_all('table', attrs={'border':"1",'cellpadding':"6",'bordercolor':"#000000"}):
    for y in x:
        try:
            if y.name == 'tr':
                print "\t".join(y.get_text().split())
       except:pass
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed regex but I will look into Beautiful Soup it looks neat

Comment: @Juicy BeautifulSoup is great Utility to parse an html page